# Multilist Field where users can add new values

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy

I'm looking to replicate the SharePoint taxonomy functionality in Sitecore - there is the ability in SharePoint to type a new value in a multivalue field and it would automatically create the new taxonomy value on save. Is there a good way to replicate this functionality in Sitecore? Will this require a custom field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it will. There are no field types that ship out of the box, that gives you that functionality.

If you are going to explore making your own customisation for this, I would suggest the `Multilist with Search` field is a good place to start.

A good place to start could be: [Have a Field Day With Custom Sitecore Fields](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2012/12/28/have-a-field-day-with-custom-sitecore-fields/)

Comment: Just to note as this was answered on another question, you should apparently avoid using the "Multilist with Search" and instead use the "AdvancedSearchList" field type. See: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/372032

Comment: It is worth providing more context, of the link so that if the link stops existing the user or future users could still have their question answered. It is worth reviewing http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the `Inline Item List field` in the past:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Inline_Item_List_Field.aspx.

It provides extra buttons to create items from the `Multilist` field so that you don't have to leave the item you are editing.  It hasn't been updated in a while so I can't speak to it's compatibility in Sitecore 8+.